# Angular15-Unit Test : Reactive FormGroup.value not reflected appropriately, after setting value to HTML Input via querySelector('#searchInput')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

```js
/** component.ts file */

import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-typeahead',
  templateUrl: './typeahead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typeahead.component.scss']
})
export class TypeaheadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private service: DataFetchService) { }
  searchForm!: FormGroup;



  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      'searchInput': ['', Validators.required]
    })

 
  }
}

/** component.spec.ts UNIT TESTING file */

import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TypeaheadComponent } from './typeahead.component';


describe('TypeaheadComponent', () => {
  let component: TypeaheadComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TypeaheadComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [TypeaheadComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TypeaheadComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });

  it('Form controls into FormGroup', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const searchElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#searchInput');
      searchElement.value = "Goog";
      searchElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.searchForm.value).toEqual({ searchInput: 'Goog' });

        /** form 
         * Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
            An error was thrown in afterAll
            Expected '' to equal 'Goog'.
                at <Jasmine>
         */
      })
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<!-- component template file -->

<div>
    <form [formGroup]="searchForm">
        <input type="text" class="searchInputStyle" formControlName="searchInput" id="searchInput" />
    </form>

</div>
```

> **Error Getting when $>ng test**
>
> ````
> Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
> An error was thrown in afterAll
> **  Expected $.searchInput = '' to equal 'Goog'.
> at <Jasmine>**
> at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/typeahead/typeahead.component.spec.ts:40:44)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:375:26)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:39)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:374:52)
> Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 2 ERROR (0 secs / 0.033 secs)
> Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10) ERROR
> An error was thrown in afterAll
> Expected $.searchInput = '' to equal 'Goog'.
> at <Jasmine>
> at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/typeahead/typeahead.component.spec.ts:40:44)
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:375:26)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:39)
> Chrome 108.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 2 ERROR (0.119 secs / 0.033 secs)`
> ```
>
> Tried googling similar on Stack overflow example and also followed following youtube
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tam0ruVGcnk
>
> my code is exactly the same, but still formGroup value is {searchInput:''}
> however expecting to get {searchInput:'Goog'}